# Yii rest api insert data in database

Tags: php, mysql, rest, yii

I have some problem with rest service.
I'm new programmer in yii framework and also I did not create any service before.
My code is next:

My controller:

```
    public function actionList()
     {
         $model=new Entryfile;
            if($_POST) {
                 $init = CJSON::decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
                 $model->attributes=$init['input'];
                 $model->eeType=($model->eeType);
                 $model->eeSize=($model->eeSize);
                 $model->eeFileName=($model->eeFileName);
                 $model->eeFileChecksum=($model->eeFileChecksum);
                 $model->eeEntryPath=($model->eeEntryPath);
                 }
         $model=new Outputfile;
            if($_POST) {
                 $init = CJSON::decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
                 $model->attributes=$init['output'];
                 $model->ofName=($model->ofName);
                 $model->ofDocumentPath=($model->ofDocumentPath);
                 $model->ofDocumentType=($model->ofDocumentType);

                 }

     }
```

Entryfile is one table, and Output file is onother table...
for input and output.
In postman I sent:

```
{ 
  "input": 
 { 
   "eeType": "doc",
   "eeSize": "1024", 
   "eeFileName": "something", 
   "eeFileChecksum": "23dsdjm34mn4", 
   "eeEntryPath": 1 
 },

  "output": 
  { 
    "ofDocumentType": "PDF", 
    "ofName": "something", 
    "ofDocumentPath": 1 
  } 
}
```

Now I only need somthing to insert data from postman to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
$model=new Outputfile;
        if($_POST) {
             $init = CJSON::decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
             $model->attributes=$init['output'];
             if($model->save());
                {
                   $this->$model->ofName=($model->ofName);
                   $this->$model->ofDocumentPath=($model->ofDocumentPath);
                   $this->$model->ofDocumentType=($model->ofDocumentType); 
                }
            // echo "\n".'Output podaci:'.print_r($init['output'],1);

             }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the save() method.

```
$model=new Entryfile;
  ...
$init = CJSON::decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$model->attributes=$init['input'];
   ...
if (!$model->save())
{
   print_r($model->getErrors());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try $model->save(false). If data is saved to the database, than just set safe attribute for the model.